# CodeIgniter Login with cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I've tried to create a Login system with a cookie of my own. The point is that
every time user log's in and checks "remember me" button, it will generate a new, 32-character cookie and saves it in the users table, column named "remember_me_token". 
If user closes browser and comes back, it should automatically sign him/her in again, but I don't seem to get it work.

If I close my browser now, open it up again and come back to my site, the cookie is still there. The problem is that every time the session expires (for testing purposes I've set it to 1 minute) it will automatically log me out and completely ignores the cookie. Is there something wrong with my methods or database queries?

Thanks in advance!

**Here's my Model:**

```
    public function checkRememberMeToken($cookie)
    {   
        $where = array (
                'remember_me_token' => $cookie
            );

        $this->db->select('*')->from('users')->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {

            return true;
        }
    }
```

**And here's my Controller:**

```
    public function loginWithCookie()
    {

        if($cookie = $this->input->cookie('sportietown')) {

            $user = $this->user_model->checkRememberMeToken($cookie);

            if($user === TRUE)
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user['user_id']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('email', $user['email']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('name', $user['name']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('profilepic', $user['profilepic']);

                redirect(base_url().'dashboard');

            } else {

                $this->load->view('/template/header');
                $this->load->view('index');
                $this->load->view('/template/footer');

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The cookie that is set and the time of the session work together. The time of the session is the amount of time the person can leave their browser idle or come back and still be recognized again.

When the user goes to a new page and the cookie is read - if the session is active the session time starts again. if you set it to only 1 minute its not going to work unless they are clicking quickly. The default in CI is 2 hours (7200 seconds) or set it to the value you want.

in CI config/config.php starting at line 235 are all the session configs. make sure they are set correctly and also make sure your cookie name does not have an underscore in it.

Comment: So the only chance to test it, is to set the session time back to default (7200 seconds), login with "remember me" checkbox checked, go to sleep and see in the morning if the cookie actually does work and I'm logged back in automatically?

Comment: You can set the session time for any value. If you need it to be 5 minutes for testing then do that. Some people set a session time of 30 days or longer because they want the website to remember the visitor. However that doesn't mean the website will treat them as "logged in". For example amazon will recognize you and what is in your shopping cart for many days - but you have to 'log in' again before making the payment and completing the purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using table for your user autologin you will need to save your user's useragent string. It has this format

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1`

Use this to identify your user each time he visits with same device then log him in.

The table should look like this : `user_id`, `useragent`